# How to Register custom handelbars helper in assemble 0.17.1

Tags: assemble, handlebarshelper

In my assemblefile.js I try to register a custom helper. The helper itself does work since i have it in use in a grunt project with assemble.

```js
assemble: {
  options: {
    helpers: ['./src/helper/custom-helper.js' ]
  }
}
```

In assemble 0.17.1 I tried it like this but it doesn´t work. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
app.helpers('./src/helper/custom-helper.js');
```

custom-helper.js:

```js
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options, params)  {

    Handlebars.registerHelper('section', function(name, options) {
        if (!this.sections) {
        this.sections = {};
    }
    this.sections[name] = options.fn(this);
    return null;;
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assemble` is built on top of the `templates` module now, so you can use the `.helper` and `.helpers` methods for registering helpers with assemble, which will register them with Handlebars. [This link](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/templates#helper) has more information on registering the helpers.

Since the `templates` api is used, you don't have to wrap the helpers with the `.register` method in your example. You can just export the helper function, then name it when registering with assemble like this:

```
// custom-helper.js
module.exports = function(name, options) {
  if (!this.sections) {
    this.sections = {};
  }
  this.sections[name] = options.fn(this);
  return null;
};

// register with assemble
var app = assemble();
app.helper('section', require('./custom-helper.js'));
```

You may also export an object with helpers and register them all at once using the `.helpers` method:

```
// my-helpers.js
module.exports = {
  foo: function(str) { return 'FOO: ' + str; },
  bar: function(str) { return 'BAR: ' + str; },
  baz: function(str) { return 'BAZ: ' + str; }
};

// register with assemble
var app = assemble();
app.helpers(require('./my-helpers.js'));
```

When registering the object with the `.helpers` method, the property keys are used for the helper names