# Different foot block per page

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js, assemble

I have this custom handelbars helper

```js
// custom-helper.js
module.exports = function(name, options) {
  if (!this._sections) {
    this.sections = {};
  }
  this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
  return null;
};

// register with assemble
var app = assemble();
app.helper('section', require('./custom-helper.js'));
```

[How to Register custom handelbars helper in assemble 0.17.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402635/how-to-register-custom-handelbars-helper-in-assemble-0-17-1)

This helper should work like here:

[Handlebars with Express: different html head for different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740214/7359129)

And in my grunt Project is does work perfectly. But in this gulp Project it´s not working.

My Layout.hbs:

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    {%body%}
  </div>
  {{{_sections.foot}}}
</body>
```

My pages that contain the _sections.foot content and the rest of the page content:

```html
--- layout: default.hbs ---

<h1>Body Blah Blah</h1>
<p>This goes in page body.</p>

{{#section 'foot'}} my custom per page foot content {{/section}}
```

What the code should do is to tage the custom content in my pages, that is this:

{{#section 'foot'}} my custom per page foot content {{/section}}

and render it  in the place that I defined in the layout:

{{{_sections.foot}}}

When I run my gulp task or assemble task I get this.
"null" is written in my rendered .html file at the position in my page.hbs, thats directly under the pages content inside #page and not after #page where my layout.hbs says to put it in.

Here are the Problems:
1. Null is rendered and not the content.
2. Even if the content would be rendered it would appear at the wrong position in html.

Comment: Inserting tags into titles is not allowed on SO.